# C++ virtual base classes: parent's copy constructor doesn't get called

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I have three classes as you can see in the code below. Notice how I have written the copy constructors.

```
#include <iostream>

class Abstract
{
public:
    Abstract(){};
    Abstract( const Abstract& other ): mA(other.mA){};
    virtual ~Abstract(){};

    void setA(double inA){mA = inA;};
    double getA(){return mA;};

    virtual void isAbstract() = 0;
protected:
    double mA;
};

class Parent : public virtual Abstract
{
public:
    Parent(){};
    Parent( const Parent& other ): Abstract(other){};
    virtual ~Parent(){};

};


class Child : public virtual Parent
{
public:
    Child(){};
    Child( const Child& other ): Parent(other){};
    virtual ~Child(){};

    void isAbstract(){};
};


int main()
{
    Child child1;
    child1.setA(5);

    Child childCopy(child1);
    std::cout << childCopy.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now why `Abstract()` gets called instead of the copy constructor `Abstract( const Abstract& other )` when `childCopy` is being constructed?

Shouldn't `Child(other)` call `Parent(other)`? And shouldn't `Parent(other)` in turn call `Abstract(other)`?

Comment: How do you know that `Parent(other)` is not called? Please add a couple of `printf`s or `cout <<`s to each constructor body to see what gets called. Please update the question with the results.

Comment: Please make all constructors initialize all data members defined in the same class, e.g. `Abstract(): mA(-1) {};`

Comment: Virtual base classes can only be initialized by the most derived class. Other constructor calls are ignored and replaced with default constructor calls.

Comment: @0x499602D2: that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: [They're all called as intended](http://ideone.com/vQoMZr)

Comment: Btw you do not need to put a `;` behind member function definitions, they end with the `}` like every function definition does.

Comment: btw2: make your return-by-value getter `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual base classes can only be initialized by the most derived class. Calls to a constructor of a virtual base from a non most-derived class are ignored and replaced with default constructor calls. This is to ensure that the virtual base subobject is initialized only once:

The correct code should place the constructor call in the most derived class' *ctor-initializer*:

```
Child(Child const& other)
    : Abstract(other) // indirect virtual bases are
                      // initialized first
    , Parent(other) // followed by direct bases
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have correctly called `Abstract`'s copy constructor, you need to specify that in the initializer list of `Child`'s copy constructor.

```
Child( const Child& other ): Abstract(other), Parent(other) {};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e3a961be8fd4d2c)

Here is the relevant quote from the standard, which states that the constructor of a virtual base class is called only in the most derived class. If it is missing, the default constructor is called instead (--if it exists).

> §12.6.2, (13.1):
>
> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8),
>     virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a
>     depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of
>     base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the
>     base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.

In particular, this is why you notice `Abstract`'s default constructor being called.

In order to avoid this pitfall, however, you can drop all user-defined copy constructors and rely on the copy constructor which is implicitly defined (which is always a good idea). [DEMO 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf5e0a7f82bb88ad)